# Google Tag Manager Element Visibility CSS Selector Not firing

Tags: html, css, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get a Tag to fire on specific steps within an api, which means I cannot use the url (it is the same throughout the checkout process).

I have found parts of the code that are different in each step and was going to fire the tag when both the specific element appears on the page and when I click the "Continue" Button. The continue button fires fine by itself, but I can't get the Element Visibility trigger to fire the tag by itself. I will group them together when finished.

```html
<textarea class="florist-one-flower-delivery-card-message" id="florist-one-flower-delivery-card-message" name="florist-one-flower-delivery-card-message"></textarea>
```

The trigger is currently:

```
Trigger Type: "Element Visibility"
Selection Method: "CSS Selector"
Element Selector: ".florist-one-flower-delivery-card-message"
```

I have also tried setting the selection method to ID and using the same selector without the "." at the beginning.

Thanks for any help!